# Create computed field in Odoo with search method through UI

Tags: odoo

If I create a custom computed field through the Odoo UI (Settings > Technical > Fields), is it possible to make this field searchable? If I were doing this on-premise via Python code, I would just add a `search` parameter to the field definition which would return a domain used to search the database. That's explained pretty clearly in the docs:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#fields

However, I am using an instance of Odoo SaaS, and I don't see any way through the UI to define the `search` method. Is it possible? What about through an XML data file?